# Unable to change the color of the sidebar in now-ui-dashboard-angular Template

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am using now-ui-dashboard-angular-v1.0.0 Template

I want to change the default red-color of the sidebar. I did Inspect and got this css -

```
 .sidebar[data-color="red"]:after,
 .off-canvas-sidebar[data-color="red"]:after {
   background: #FF3636; 
   }
```

But after changing its  color to -

```
 .sidebar[data-color="green"]:after,
.off-canvas-sidebar[data-color="green"]:after {

  background: #d4f932 !important;
}
```

it still doesn't change. Please help.

Comment: if you change the color in dev tool does is it changing?

Comment: what is dev tool ? You mean original template ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code.

```
:host>>> .sidebar:before, :host>>> .sidebar:after, :host>>> .off-canvas-sidebar:before, :host>>> .off-canvas-sidebar:after 
{
        background-color: #064BEC !important;
}
```

Please check the below result image:

[image]

Comment: @Techdive I have updated the answer. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.sidebar[data-color="red"]:after,
 .off-canvas-sidebar[data-color="red"]:after {
    background: #d4f932 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Sidebar colour is the **$primary-color** of template.
You can find the colours in assets/scss/now-ui-dashboard

/_variables.scss starting with line 51 where is the primary color set: $primary-color: #f96332 !default.

```
$primary-color: #f96332 !default.
```

Alternatively, you choose to change the sidebar alone so you go to
.. /src/app/components/sidebar/sidebar.component.html

On line 1, replace red with blue or your colour of choice.

```
<div class="sidebar" data-color="blue">
```

Link: https://demos.creative-tim.com/now-ui-dashboard-pro/docs/1.0/components/colors.html